# Entity Framework 6.1.1 When using same foreign key property in two child classes giving “property name is already defined” error

Tags: entity-framework

I am Stuck with the TPH issue in Entity Framework 6.1.1 When using same foreign key propertie in the two child classes I am getting error : "One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:\r\n\r\ xyz: Name: Each property name in a type must be unique. Property name ' ' is already defined.\r\n". Please refere last example in given link . http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/583   Any alternate solution will be appreciated.....

Comment: Please show us some code

Comment: Consider using  `notmapped` attribute

Comment: Please refer last example from below link: http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/583

Comment: @ilanS: I have to map this property with primary forign key relationship.

Comment: I have shifted this property into the Parent Class and it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I have noticed that this happens when you establish a navigation property, and then add a scale property, both properties (scalar and navigation) associated with a single foreign key. Perhaps your case.

Comment: Please note, the language to use here is English.